# Footer not responding to center commands

Tags: css, footer, centering

I'm making a very simple website and I've got a problem with my footer: it's not centering. I've done all the margin-left:auto; and right things, and the problem persists in Chrome and Firefox. The code:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:10;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height:35px;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:#363636;
  /* Style info that has nothing to do with the problem below this line */
  box-shadow: 1px -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow:1px -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow:1px -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);  
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Already tried typing in "display:inline-block;".
The index.html code (ofc it's still in-dev, has nothing): http://d.pr/btSa

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your footer is not centering with margin is because of the `postion:fixed`.  Remove that and it will obey your `margin` `auto`'s.

If you need it to be `fixed`, update your css to look like this:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:10;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -500px;
  width: 1000px;
  height:35px;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:#363636;
  /* Style info that has nothing to do with the problem below this line */
}
```

note adding the `bottom:0;`, `left:50%;` and updating the `margin` properties.

Comment: Thanks, it sorta worked, but it doesn't stay on the bottom of the page w/o position fixed. Bottom:0px; doesn't seem to work. Here: http://d.pr/cVPT

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution that uses your `postion:fixed`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the:

position: fixed

Try without it. If you want it stuck to the bottom try with other positions (absolute and etc). Try instead of with margin then to use left: auto and right: auto. since on fixed position i believe margins don't matter.

If you insist on it, try putting the footer as 100% width, make it fixed position and wherever you want it, then put the content in a wrapper inside the fixed footer and give that a margin: 0 auto. it will center inside the footer.

Comment: Relative brought it up, with absolute the problem persisted. Fixed and left/right:auto; didn't work either. The wrapper part I didn't really understand, I did it the way I thought was right and width:100% made it occupy the whole page. So nothing worked ;x. Really trying to think why it's not working the proper way the way I first wrote it.

Comment: then try left and right at 50%.

the other thing, the wrapper stuff i was talking about was this:

http://pastebin.com/yLJt1n3A

Answer (score -2):

Try to use your footer in a table and set the alignment of td to center

Comment: `table`s should not be used for layout purposes.

Comment: Sorry, don't like tables. Thanks though.